# ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using mysql 5.5 and Rails 3.2.13. I have such table:

```
'CREATE TABLE `visit` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uri` varchar(2048) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `remote_ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_agent` varchar(2048) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `client_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_posting_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `assessment_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idv_visit_assess_id` (`assessment_id`),
  KEY `fk_visit_client` (`client_id`),
  KEY `fk_visit_position` (`position_id`),
  KEY `fk_visit_job_posting` (`job_posting_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28649 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci'
```

And such model:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :visit_actions
end
```

From time to time i can observe such errors in my production logs('remote_ip' was changed):

```
#<ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hirex/visit`, CONSTRAINT `fk_visit_job_posting` FOREIGN KEY (`job_posting_id`) REFERENCES `job_posting` (`id`)): INSERT INTO `visit` (`assessment_id`, `client_id`, `created_at`, `job_posting_id`, `position_id`, `remote_ip`, `updated_at`, `uri`, `user_agent`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, '2013-09-13 00:25:02', 8716, NULL, '127.0.0.1', '2013-09-13 00:25:02', '/applicant/exit_job_posting', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)')>
```

I've spent several days trying to reproduce this issue but haven't succeed. It's Ok if i'm trying to insert null instead of real 'job_posting_id' or id of unexciting job_posting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is that you (or someone else is trying to add `job_posting_id` which doesn't exist in `job_posting` table. I don't have too much code to say why this is happening, one of the most common reasons is that someone rendered a form (with `job_posting` select) and before it was submitted, someone else removed given `job_posting`.

Rails is very efficient in working without foreign key constraints - is there any particular reason why you enforce them?